# Passing parameter in URL and then rendering errors with 'new' action if validation not passed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, routes, render

I have encountered issue that I suspect is not that hard to fix and simply my lack of experience is making it hard.

I have my route

```
match '(/:client_id)/signup',   to: 'users#new'
```

Now if client is sending link to whoever www.myappurl.com/123/signup the user will signup and his user model will receive client_id as parameter (which I need later on).

Controller:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  if signed_in?
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end

def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])

  if @user.save
    sign_in @user
    flash[:success] = t("users.new.welcome")
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render 'new' #and this is the problem
  end
end
```

And the problem is, that when users submits his application, and information he provides doesn't pass the validation then 'new' action is rendered but I loose this :client_id parameter and therefore association between him and client.

I have tried redirect_to and passing params. This works, but error messages are not displayed.

Any ideas how to fix it?

EDIT

my debug before submitting invalid info:

```
controller: users
action: new
locale: en
client_id: '2'
```

and after:

```
!binary "dXRmOA==": ✓
!binary "YXV0aGVudGljaXR5X3Rva2Vu": ldtdjuWAWHB052qY3ASoH1Mv3XYtrdRcL56DgSaYC0Q=
!binary "dXNlcg==": !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
!binary "Zmlyc3RfbmFtZQ==": ''
!binary "bGFzdF9uYW1l": ''
!binary "ZW1haWw=": ''
!binary "Y2xpZW50X2lk": '2'
!binary "cGFzc3dvcmQ=": ''
!binary "cGFzc3dvcmRfY29uZmlybWF0aW9u": ''
!binary "Y29tbWl0": Create my account
action: create
controller: users
locale: en
```

SERVER LOG

```
Started POST "/en/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-16 07:10:31 +0800
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ldtdjuWAWHB052qY3ASoXYtrdRcL56DgSaYC0Q=", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"", "last_name"=>"", "email"=>"", "client_id"=>"2", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Create my account", "locale"=>"en"}
(0.4ms) BEGIN
User Exists (2.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('') LIMIT 1
(0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (18.6ms)
Rendered users/_fields_for_registration_no_verification.html.erb (36.9ms)
Rendered users/_password_fields.html.erb (3.6ms)
Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (77.5ms)
Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered layouts/_google_tracking_code (0.0ms)
User Load (2.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" IS NULL  LIMIT 1
Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (8.7ms)
Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (1.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 437ms (Views: 213.4ms | ActiveRecord: 14.9ms)
```

EDIT

I have found real source of the problem (different from answer below). Issue was that when I was using hidden field in my form I was using following code:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :client_id, { :value => params[:client_id]} %>
```

It turned out that once I deleted the `{ :value => params[:client_id]}` part everything started to work as expected after unsuccessful registration. Never the less thanks for help.

Comment: and I pass client_id in hidden field in the form_for if anyone is asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because when the validation fails and new is rendered, your `:cliend_id` is lost from the `@user` object.

```
def new
  if params[:client_id]
    @user = User.new(:client_id => params[:client_id])
  else
    @user = User.new
  end 
  if signed_in?
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

And in your `users/new.html.haml` view make sure you have the hidden field for `:client_id`.

```
=form_for @user do |u|
  =f.hidden_field :client_id  #This will prevent your client_id from getting lost when validation fails.
```

More cleaner approach will be to use before_filter to your new action. Hope you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately client_id is still lost if I try your solution

Comment: Can you paste your server log when the new is hit first time with a `:client_id`?

Comment: I just wrote a small app which stores the client_id during signup. Please check https://github.com/deepakprasanna/signup

Comment: Thanks mate, appreciate the effort. Your app doesn't handle the unsuccessful user creation, therefore problem can not be replicated.

User controller -> create action -> no "else" :(

Comment: What do you mean unsuccessful user creation? Validation fail while creating a new user?

Comment: It does have an else part. check -> https://github.com/deepakprasanna/signup/blob/master/app/controllers/users_controller.rb#L53

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. Let me check how this behaves in my app

Comment: Ok, I have checked. And it works. Your earlier solution must have worked and I just missed something.

Comment: For some reason only worked once:| But I have finally found the problem, Please see above. Anyway, thanks for help mate.